# File not found/Invalid Argument

Tags: python, directory, package, backtrader

Although my folder is in the correct path, the function can't find it.

I am relatively new to programming, maybe some obvious mistakes?

```
import backtrader as bt

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname=r'D:\Programme\Visual Studio Code\Projekte\D_Candles.csv', dtformat=2)

cerebro.adddata(data)

cerebro.run()

cerebro.plot()
```

All dependencies and packages were installed.

Error Message:

```
PS D:\Programme\Visual Studio Code\Projekte> & C:/Users/William/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "d:/Programme/Visual Studio Code/Projekte/Trading/backtest.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programme\Visual Studio Code\Projekte\Trading\backtest.py", line 9, in <module>
    cerebro.run()
  File "C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\backtrader\cerebro.py", line 1127, in run
    runstrat = self.runstrategies(iterstrat)
  File "C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\backtrader\cerebro.py", line 1210, in runstrategies
    data._start()
  File "C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\backtrader\feed.py", line 203, in _start
    self.start()
  File "C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\backtrader\feeds\csvgeneric.py", line 88, in start 
    super(GenericCSVData, self).start()
  File "C:\Users\William\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\backtrader\feed.py", line 674, in start
    self.f = io.open(self.p.dataname, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Programme\\Visual Studio Code\\Projekte\\D_Candles.csv'
PS D:\Programme\Visual Studio Code\Projekte>
```

What I tried so far:

- just tiping the folder name, not the whole path
- switching the backslashes, tried //, \, /, \ and with & without r
- copied the folder in an other path
- it is not because of spaces between words

I really appreciate your help.
Even if you just know an alternative function I could try...

Comment: "...and many more here..." - that may not contain  the clue for what's wrong to you, but it may to us. Always include the full stacktrace. StackOverflow will give the box a scrollbar if it's too long, so don't worry about how it looks.

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` Does the error actually print the name of the missing file?  You left that part out...

Comment: Your program script is in the `Projekte\Trading` directory.  Do you expect the csv file to be in that same directory?

Comment: I edited the Error Message, so that you fully can see what's going on. Yes, it prints the whole file path. And yes, I expect that the CSV file is in that same directory...because it is.

Comment: Are you sure that `D_Candles.csv` is the name of your file? I can see in your output that `D:\Programme\Visual Studio Code\Projekte` should exist, try running `dir` there.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
r'D:\Programme\Visual Studio Code\Projekte\D_Candles.csv'
```

it indicates the variable as a  raw string which  treats the backslash character as a literal character. it is useful when a string needs to contain a backslash, such as for a regular expression or Windows directory path

Comment: Your advice is not bad advice, but not the issue for OP. They indicate they already tried switching  the backslashes for slashes and none of `\P`, `\D` and `\V` are special characters. I.e.  `'\\P' == '\P'` and `r'\P' == '\P'`.

Comment: I tried that and put it in as you see now in my edited version. But that did not solve the problem